# Value of the field std::numeric_limits<T>::digits for floating point types T in C++, GCC compiler

Tags: c++, gcc, floating-point, ieee-754

I am using the gcc compiler (Linux, gcc --version is 4.8.2) for c++ programming. I am concerned with the template specialization of `std::numeric_limits<T>` for floating point types `T` (`float`, `double`, `long double`). More specifically, I am interested in the value of the static member `static constexpr int digits` of `std::numeric_limits<T>` for floating point types `T`.

To my knowledge, in the current C++ standard it says that the value of `digits` is the *number of radix digits in the mantissa*. I printed the value of `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits` for the different floating point types on my machine (floating point types implement IEEE754 according to the field `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559`) and I am a bit surprised about the result: I.e. for `T=float` it says `24`.

It is my understanding that the *Single* type (i.e. `float`) has - according to IEEE754 - a mantissa (the significand of a floating point number) of 23 bits (while there is 1 sign bit and an exponent of 8 bits, so 32 bits total). So why is `digits` set to `24`? The value of `digits` for `double` is `53` instead of 52 (number of bits in the mantissa for *Double* according to IEEE754).

Probably some subtle (or not so subtle?) floating point issue, but I'd like to know.

Comment: It's probably counting the implicit leading 1 (so it would be incorrect for denormals)